# Sencha Touch - Grid Layout

Tags: javascript, html, sencha-touch

I am new to Sencha Touch. Its pretty slick. But one thing I can't seem to figure out is how to do a Grid style layout. For instance, I am creating a basic login screen that looks like the following:

```
Username
[TextBox Goes Here]

Password
[Password Field Goes Here]

[LoginButton] | [RegisterButton]
```

Displaying just the username / password fields is pretty easy with the default FormPanel. However, as you can see, I want to have a Login Button and a Register button on the same row. The previous textboxes should span the columns of both the buttons width wise.

How do I do this with Sencha? If it was HTML, I would do the following:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <table border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>
      <tr><td colspan='2'>Username</td></tr>
      <tr><td colspan='2'><input type='text' /></td></tr>

      <tr><td colspan='2'>Password</td></tr>
      <tr><td colspan='2'><input type='password' /></td></tr>

      <tr>
        <td><input type='button' value='Login' /></td>
        <td><input type='button' value='Register' /></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

try floating your login button left, and register right. If your column is defined in width that should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about table layout ?  Items in table layout have got `colspan` and `rowspan` properties.

Comment: I guess I'm missing something. I do not see a table layout in the SENCHA API (http://docs.sencha.com/touch/1-1/#!/api/Ext). Can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll have to use a panel with a vbox layout containing panels with hbox layouts that contain your form fields.  There's no table layout as far as I can tell.  The alternative is to use an XTemplate but I don't think it'd be worth the hassle.